# IntelliJ: Missing messages window option in "tool window" menu

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-3.0

The problem is that after "some changes" (update/changes in project settings my messages window is missing. I am unable to find that in Android Studio 3.1 Canary and in Android Studio 3.0.1 stable version for any of my projects. It looks like that (screen attached) - the shortcut CMD + 0 doesn't work either. Does anyone know what can be the reason?

[image: Tool window - screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This is Google's intended behavior. Check [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70923234).

> Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)
>
> This is expected behavior in latest canary build, release notes needs to be updated.